# Change Text - Inside A button, inside a Canvas, inside a GameObject: Access all the texts inside of hierchy?

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject, text

```
//....
Gameobject tile;
int count = 1f;
float posX = 0;
float posY = 0;
....//

GameObject blueTile = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("block_blue"));
tile = (GameObject)Instantiate(blueTile, transform);

for loop {
   ...
   ...
   tile.GetComponent().GetComponentInChildren().text = count.ToString();
   tile.transform.position = new Vector2((float)posX, (float)posY);
   count++;
}
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see by the image.
My line of thinking goes like this; I used to create Flash/AS3 Applications and Games. I have used a number of API's and they usually have a lot in common. Unity, however, is very different and I may have not grasped the key concepts.

I want to access my PreFab, named in Assets/Resources (the root path)

"block_blue"

All I wan to do is set up a row and columns of a box with a number inside of it.

Before you go and ask, why the complicated mix of Objects? Well, Adobe had MovieClip and use of layers and also use of a timeline. Unity doesn't seem to have this in setting up a Scene (the Stage in Flash).

So, I set up a block that looks like this (right of main image 66):
It's a Canvas, to hold a Button, the button has a text. To move the Canvas, I put the Canvas inside a GameObject. This, to me, is like a MovieClip in Flash API.

**GameObject > ButtonLight, Button > TextBlack, Text**

I need to access TextBlack and also Text. Pretty easy right? I've been at this for 4 days, many many hours.

EDIT: It seems that it is working, somewhat.

Looking at the reference photo and the Hierarchy reference, it looks like the blackText behind the blueText is changing as expected. But I cannot access the top BlueText. The Blue Text is also a child of type Text, but it's a second (layer?) copy of the text inside of the Button. So, it's getting the first Child Text, but how to access the second Text?

Comment: Unity Doc, not good. If you are a Unity Expert, maybe? But for reference as a person learning Unity, not helpful at all. It's like an Engineering schematic, not a reference manual. No examples. Here's a pointer, what a pointer looks like. It's why I even kept my old C books, for the examples in the text. But now API's change so often, it's not even worth buying texts. "this decision on your coding choice is deprecated" - which means "the masters of this API changed it dude, so get lost with that". It's a contributing reason I decided to stop pursuing a profession in/and use my CS degree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
[image]

As you can see by the images, I had to change the "Hierarchy". In the attempt to utilize this as we do in Adobe Flash (AS3) in using-layers, this is how I accomplished this. To give it a "MovieClip" Feel from the Adobe Flash API approach.


I replaced **ButtonLight** in the hierarchy, with **Image**.


I removed **TextBlack** from Button and **Added a Shadow component** to the Text inside the Button Component. The new hierarchy is in the image.


Here are the 3 syntax I used, with this Hierarchy, to accomplish the goal:

> Hierarchy
>
> - GameObject
> - Image - > Color
> - Button - > Image - > Color
>
>   > Text - > Color & Shadow Component instead of a second Text

***Button Color***

- public void changeButtonColor(GameObject gameObject, Color color)
- gameObject.GetComponentInChildren().GetComponent().color = color;

***Font Color***

- public void changeFontColor(GameObject gameObject, Color color)
- gameObject.GetComponentInChildren().color = color;

***Image Color***

- public void changeTileColor(GameObject gameObject, Color color)
- gameObject.GetComponentInChildren().color = color;

I was able to create 3 functions/methods to change the attributes within the Hierarchy Layers of the GameObject Prefab, "block". Where, the "block" is a GameObject with the given hierarchy above. A layers approach.

Answer (score 1):

[`GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInChildren.html) traverses the whole object tree below an object using a depth-first search until it finds the first component of the requested type and returns it. I would not advise to use that method unless you are in a situation where you are certain that there is only one child with that component and there will never be a reason to add a second one.

If you want to get **all** the text components in **all** the descendants of an object, use [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html). Note the extra `s` behind `Component`. It doesn't just return the first Component it finds. It traverses the whole tree collecting all the components of that type and then returns them as an array of 0 or more Components. So when you want to change the color of all the texts of a given object, do

```
foreach(UI.Text text in theGameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<UI.Text>()) {
     text.color = Color.blue;
}
```

Caveat: When you have very large object hierarchies, then this method can become slow. With object hierarchies of 5, I don't think you are at that point yet. But it might become a problem with 100s of nested objects.

So when you want to change the color of a large number of text nodes in a deeply nested hierarchy very frequently, then I would look if it's possible to assign the same Material to all the texts and control the color by changing that shared material.

---

By the way: You can find a lot more useful methods for navigating the scene graph in [the documentation of the GameObject class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html).

Comment: This seems logical; haven't grasped the concepts yet. But familiar with overhead,cost. Getting started with Unity. Flash/AS3 went down it was tough. Android-API difficult for mundane tasks. I only found Unity, but took took time to decide to plunge into the API. I did a lot of refactoring recently on this project. Layers (easy, my world) but then Z messes up (auto-assign). It took me days to figure out the culprit. Like Z trumps layers? It's buggy in that design. And then Prefab, original, partial Fab? Huh? Materials and Shaders, uh-oh sounds like 3D. Took months to get familiar w/ Blender.

Comment: @ejbytes Please ask any new questions you have which are not directly related to this answer as new questions.